# Parse & Swift - How to Reduce Server Load/Requests?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, parse-platform

I've been developing an application that has a home page, similar to that of Instagram's where the number of comments is displayed below a post as the user scrolls. Once the user taps on the label with the number of comments, the actuals comments will then load onto the screen. I've been trying to achieve something similar to that with my application, but I feel as if the method that I am doing this with is sending to many requests (queries) to the server in order to get the number of comments to display below each post. I was wondering if there was a more efficient/concise way to do this that would reduce the server load, but still have the same effect.

To add more context (Note: I'm using Parse):

- I have a class named Posts which contains the posts
- I have a class named Comments which contains all of the submitted comments. In order to obtain the comments for a particular post, I query for comments (which have a column named: "parentObjectID") whose column ("parentObjectID") matches with the parent post's object ID.

Example code is below:

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Comments")
    query.whereKey("parentObjectID", equalTo: objectIDs[indexPathNums])

    query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")

    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("An error occured (USQVC Comments Query)")
        }else {

            if let tempArray = objects {
                for comment in tempArray {

                    if let x = comment {

                        myArray.append(x)
                    }



                }
                commentsCount = myArray.count
                myArray.removeAll()
            }

        }
    }
```

Even though they've updated their UI, I just wanted to include a picture in case what I was describing was unclear:

[image]

I'd appreciate it if anybody could help me out with this. Thanks!

Comment: You can map some number of comments into post lets say 20. If user scrolls down to 20 you can make a call to get the rest of comments. There should be mapping in Parse Server API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! After reading, this actually got me thinking. Another solution COULD possibly be to add a column to each post called numOfComments. Every time the user adds a comment the number is fetched, incremented, and saved. This would allow for the total number of comments to be displayed on the main page without too many server requests. The only issue that I could foresee with this is if 2+ users save the post at the same time or if a user with a slow connection causes the number to decrement from what it was just recently updated to be while their connection was loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out in your comment above, you certainly can use the function `incrementKey` to increment the `numberOfComments`.

The best part is, this method is atomic, that means no matter how many people like the same post at the same time, say 5 people like a photo at exact same time, `numberOfComments` will increment by 5 instead of 1.

So this function will be executed one by one instead of concurrently. You absolutely can use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ended up using that method and it works perfectly. It's also great to hear that there won't be any issues when it comes to multiple users incrementing the `numberOfComments` at the same time.